# ps3 applications development

Tags: playstation3

can anyone tell what to do develop ps3 applications (or) games after we install linux on ps3.

and other thing is that can we develop ps3 games on window platform for that what tools needed,its little bit of confusing.

can anyone clarify this?

Comment: this probably belongs on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: I can see how you might feel that this was inappropriately closed---the first question begin about windows and this one about linux---but the *answer* is the same: get the DevKit or install *on* an oler PS3. Please do not post repeated duplicates. If you are still unhappy with this close, flag your question for moderator attention and ask if they will help.

Comment: I've merged these; please stop multiple-posting. If this is a *different* question, then fine; but these 4 were ultimately the same question.

Comment: If you just want to create homebrew games, you could look at Blu-ray Disc Java, which lets you code games using Java and run them on both PS3, PS4 and XB1 from the same disc. See www.blu-play.com

Answer (score 8):

Currently, the only legitimate way to develop for the Play Station 3 is to buy the [development kit](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/news/2009/03/sony-announces-lower-cost-ps3-dev-tools.ars) and a license from Sony.  Recent hacks enable homebrew applications but there's currently only Sony's leaked SDK - building applications with this would probably be illegal.

A Homebrew SDK is in the works, but you would not be able to distribute your applications or games through official methods using this SDK.

To compile homebrew on Windows, you will likely need to use [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org) and an available [PS3 Tool Chain](http://github.com/ooPo/ps3toolchain/tree/development).  It's unlikely that a compiler will exist or even be made for Windows, but Cygwin should allow you to emulate the linux tools available.

In summary, if you want to do it legit then you need a license and a dev kit from Sony.  If you're just doing it for fun then I suggest you use Google to find more information on PS3 homebrew development.

Comment: Hi andy,you came to say that,with the homebrew sdk we can develop ps3 applications on the windows platform

Comment: @Arivazhagan: you would likely need to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to run the compiler that builds the Homebrew.  You're much better off searching Google and looking through the homebrew sites.

Comment: Hi andy,is there any difference between ps3 sdk and ps3 homebrew sdk or both are same,and another thing is,is this sdk alone enough to develop ps3 applications on windows

Comment: @Arivazhagan: There will be huge differences between the official SDK and the homebrew SDK.  And SDK is an interface to the hardware.  Like I said, you would probably need Cygwin to build the applications, regardless of the SDK.  The open source PS3 tool chain might include the necessary components you need, you should check it out.  I don't think I'll be able to help you further than that, though - you're much better off checking out the PS3 hacking forums for further help.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Wikipedia page on OtherOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OtherOS) for some basic information and plenty of pointers. Beware that you're going to be restricted in what you can do, Linux does not have access to the full machine.

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert - but:

To develop PS3 games you need a PS3 developer kit. Afaik it can't be done simply by installing linux on a PS3. The developer kit is licensed from Sony and - to the best of my knowledge - require some kind of license payment and/or approval process as an official PS3 developer/house.

Sony released a small home-development kit, including a keyboard, mouse and harddrive for the old (non-slim) PlayStation 2 back in the day. That kit was linux driven and contained libraries to utilize graphics and controllers. The last I heard that idea was scrapped by Sony.

Comment: Also, linux support is cancelled. And you didn't even have full hardware access, so don't bother anyway...

Answer (score 0):

There was a method to install another OS on the PS3, and a lot of people installed Linux.  Look through your docs (and maybe on the web) for "PS3 OtherOS" or "PS3 Other OS".  Unfortunately Sony has recently removed the ability to install another OS, so you need a unit that hasn't had a recent firmware update.

Installing Linux means you have (most of) the system at your hands.

Comment: hi dash-tom-bang after we installed linux on ps3,what tools needed to  develop games on ps3.

Comment: I suppose you'll need a text editor and a compiler; presumably both vim and gcc are installed in the process.  I'm sure there are many homebrew sites out there that can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need an official Development Kit from Sony in order to develop games for the PS3. I believe it does run in a modified Linux environment, but I cannot confirm this for sure (perhaps we have someone on SO who develops PS3 titles and can fill us in?)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a PS3 dev kit to do it properly. While one used to be able to install Linux on the PS3, it's a feature that has now been disabled. Even if you do manage to find a PS3 that is still able to accept Linux you'll be using a largely divergent API (from what commecial PS3 games are built on) and you wont' have access to many of the more powerful graphical functionality.

While you can build a game largely on Windows you'll need to port it property to run on PS3. You can't just hit compile on Windows and have it run on the PS3.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread, I see that no one has yet mentioned an alternative option that has been available for both PlayStation 3 (and later) and Xbox One (and later) from the very beginning: Blu-ray Disc Java, abbreviated BD-J.

These consoles feature a Blu-ray Player, and all Blu-ray players can run JavaME as part of the Blu-ray specification. This means you can actually code games and apps with JavaME, and run it on these game consoles from the very same disc.

So if you're just looking to create some homebrew games for fun, then BD-J is a very attractive option. Because:

- you can run your homebrew games on many gaming consoles from the very same disc
- there's no expensive SDK to buy, you simply code JavaME in whatever IDE you want
- there's no approval process, you just create your own disc and make the ISO downloadable

---

Here's a few YouTube example videos of various BD-J Xlets running on PS3, showing that the platform is quite capable of running homebrew stuff:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_E9VaXywG0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxMpLB_ZsDs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKadWBm9CQA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bC5FV-2AY4

And a few useful links:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javame/bluray-142687.html

http://www.tvwithoutborders.com/

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=38044.0